# Save shapefile as grouped/layered vector file

Tags: qgis, vector, svg, natural-earth, kartograph

I want to get the [10m natural earth countries file](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-0-countries/) into a Mercator projection and then into a vector file (SVG, ai, etc) where for each country, its main land and any of its islands are in a single group/layer.

Using QGIS I can change the projection and export a dfx, then open the dfx in Illustrator. But the layers are not grouped by country (e.g. Greece is like 20 different layers - which is fine, but they are not together in a group or layer so there is no way to select "Greece" as a whole).

In QGIS I found the "Select Features by area or single click" button. If I click on Greece using that pointer, it correctly selects ALL of the Greek islands as a group. I see I can export that as it's own file. But I don't want to have to do that 247 times and then resize and puzzle back every country into the world again.

I found Kartograph.py and spent hours trying to install it using the terminal, which I'm not good at, so failed there.

Need some help/suggestions!

Comment: I have done this in ArcGIS to Illustrator - but the principals remain the same. You will have to isolate the layer (e.g. Greece Boundary) and create a new print composer with your data and export the Greece Boundary as an .svg. I used .eps format in ArcGIS as it is an option. In that you will get a single layer you can manipulate in Illustrator (or whatever Vector program you use)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried Print Composer in QGIS, but it seems you'd have to export every country individually, then reassemble them on a page. Also, the svg it exported, crashed Illustrator (QGIS admits it is a buggy process). Appreciate your idea though.